# Bash prompt breakdown

Tags: ubuntu, bash, prompt

Can anyone explain the Ubuntu's bash prompt?

It's basically username@box:~$ but the part that confuses me is $.
Is it just a letter that can be of preference, or it has some actual meaning?

Answer (score 5):

"`$`" was the default prompt string in `sh`, the [Bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell). It doesn't have any special meaning besides showing that you are a normal user (the default prompt for root is "`#`").

Since `bash` ("Bourne Again" shell) is a derivative of `sh`, it continues to use `$`/`#` as part of its default prompt. Take a look at http://www.gilesorr.com/bashprompt/howto/x170.html and `bash`'s manual page for information on how to customize it.

Comment: In Mac OS X, the root account is also deactivated by default, but you can get a root shell with `sudo -s` (or `sudo sh` or whatever). Can't you do something similar in Ubuntu? So even with the root account disabled, having the prompt change from $ to # is useful for keeping track of whether or not you're in a superuser shell.

Comment: @Spiff yeah that works, but the normal way is to use sudo.

Comment: It also changes for different shells.  cshell/tcshell uses '%' not '$'